# Bad Escapement & Unclosed String

Tags: javascript, string, jslint

```
var freebie = ' \
    <div class="item'+last+'" data-type="psd" data-visited="false"> \
      <div class="baseBubble" /> \
      <div class="baseStroke" /> \
      <div class="baseThickerStroke" /> \
      <div class="thumbnail"> \
        <div class="overlay" /> \
        <img src="'+item['thumb'][0]+'" width="'+item['thumb'][1]+'" height="'+item['thumb'][2]+'" /> \
      </div> \
    </div>';
```

Does anyone know why this is returning 2 errors in JSLint?

Here's an image of the 2 errors:

[image]

Comment: It would not surprise me at all if Mr Crockford disapproves of using \ on the end of lines. Also, from the JSLint help: _"JSLint also checks for the occurrence of '</' in string literals. You should always write '<\/' instead."_ - that could be the "bad escapement" part. (Your code works, does it? If so I'd ignore those "errors".)

Comment: Yeah it works, was just a curiosity point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, you need to configure JSLint to tolerate ECMAScript 5.

This can be done with:

```
/*jslint es5: true, all-your-other-jslint-options */
```

---

Long answer:

The sequence, `\` followed by a line terminator, was not actually valid Javascript until recently (version 5, December 2009).

From the previous iteration (version 3) of the ECMAScript (ECMA-262) standard, section 7.8.4 states: (with some irrelevant entries removed):

```
StringLiteral ::
    " DoubleStringCharacters(opt) "
    ' SingleStringCharacters(opt) '

SingleStringCharacters ::
    SingleStringCharacter SingleStringCharacters(opt)

SingleStringCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not single-quote ' or backslash \ or LineTerminator
    \ EscapeSequence
```

So the sequence you have ends up at that last line above, a single `\` followed by the syntax element `EscapeSequence`. Examining that further:

```
EscapeSequence ::
    CharacterEscapeSequence
    0 [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]
    HexEscapeSequence
    UnicodeEscapeSequence

CharacterEscapeSequence ::
    SingleEscapeCharacter
    NonEscapeCharacter

SingleEscapeCharacter :: one of
    ' " \ b f n r t v

NonEscapeCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator

EscapeCharacter ::
    SingleEscapeCharacter
    DecimalDigit
    x
    u

HexEscapeSequence ::
    x HexDigit HexDigit

UnicodeEscapeSequence ::
    u HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
```

Since the next character after `\` is neither `0`, `x` or `u`, the only alternative is `CharacterEscapeSequence` which boils down to either `SingleEscapeCharacter` (not the case since the line terminator is not one of those characters listed ) or `NonEscapeCharacter` (which explicitly *excludes* the line terminator as a possibility).

There's also this note at the bottom of that section:

> NOTE: A 'LineTerminator' character cannot appear in a string literal, even if preceded by a backslash . The correct way to cause a line terminator character to be part of the string value of a string literal is to use an escape sequence such as \n or \u000A.

---

Now, ECMAScript 5 *changed* that a little. Starting from there, they modified the definition of `SingleStringCharacter` thus:

```
SingleStringCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not one of ' or \ or LineTerminator
    \ EscapeSequence 
    LineContinuation

LineContinuation ::
    \ LineTerminatorSequence
```

and modified the note to be:

> NOTE: A line terminator character cannot appear in a string literal, except as part of a LineContinuation to produce the empty character sequence. The correct way to cause a line terminator character to be part of the String value of a string literal is to use an escape sequence such as \n or \u000A.

And, rather than break JSLint for all the current scripts out there, the authors intelligently decided to make ECMAScript 5 support optional, requiring a change to the JSLint options to activate it. That way, it will only allow ECMAScript 5 if you explicitly tell it so.

You can visit the http://www.jslint.com/ website and confirm this:

```
Code:
    var xyzzy = ' \
    hello";
Error:
    Problem at line 1 character 16: This is an ES5 feature.
var xyzzy = ' \
    Problem at line 2 character 13: Unclosed string.
hello";
    Problem at line 2 character 13: Stopping. (66% scanned).
```

If you then scroll down to the flags section, there's an entry for `Tolerate ES5 syntax` which will, when set, remove that error.

Comment: Yeah I mean it doesn't stop it from running, just curious to why it's an error, thanks.

Comment: @Brogrammer, as to why it's an error, I've updated my answer with the ECMAScript syntax details. As to why it runs at all, well, that's probably an result of not-quite-so-standards-compliant implementations.

Comment: Which version of the standard are you referring to? The standard I was looking at (ECMA-262) says that a _LineContinuation_ within a string literal is a backslash followed by a _LineTerminatorSequence_. "A line terminator cannot occur within any token except a _StringLiteral_. Line terminators may only occur within a _StringLiteral_ token as part of a _LineContinuation_." http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: @nnnnnn: I was looking at 3. A change was made at 5.0 to allow this sequence, so I've updated the answer. Most likely JSLint is working on either older or stricter rules.

Comment: Cool. I've never worried too much about line continuation syntax because I don't like to use it anyway - I'd rather concatenate separate strings for each line because I find it easier to spot errors. But maybe that's just me.