# jshint error: "Bad escaping of EOL. Use option multistr if needed." but multistr is true

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have following .jshintrc file and use `grunt-contrib-jshint`:

```
{
"predef": [
    "after",
    "afterEach",
    "before",
    "beforeEach",
    "describe",
    "expect",
    "it",
    "jasmine",
    "ls",
    "moment",
    "runs",
    "sinon",
    "should",
    "spyOn",
    "vex",
    "waits",
    "waitsFor",
    "xit",
    "xdescribe"
    "Zombie"
],

"asi" : false,
"bitwise" : true,
"boss" : false,
"browser" : true,
"curly" : true,
"debug": false,
"devel": false,
"eqeqeq": true,
"evil": false,
"expr": true,
"forin": false,
"immed": true,
"jquery" : true,
"latedef" : false,
"laxbreak": false,
"multistr": true,
"newcap": true,
"noarg": true,
"node" : true,
"noempty": false,
"nonew": true,
"onevar": false,
"plusplus": false,
"regexp": false,
"strict": false,
"sub": false,
"trailing" : true,
"undef": true,
"unused": "vars"
}
```

As you see there is a line `multistr: true`, but it still throws me errors as:

```
Linting public/js/homepage.js...ERROR
[L93:C29] W043: Bad escaping of EOL. Use option multistr if needed.
```

Comment: Looks like this is the same question as asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832052/bad-escaping-of-eol

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma after `"xdescribe"`.

(This is why I always format my JSON like that:

```
{ "otherdef": false
, "predef":
, [ "after"
  , "afterEach"
  , "before"
  , "beforeEach"
  , "describe"
  , "expect"
  , "it"
  ]
, "foo": "bar"
, "fob": "baz"
}
```

so that missing commas are very visible)

Comment: unfortunately didn't help :(